# Recuperar um valor final de um json em Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Tem como recuperar um valor de um resultado de uma url pelo jQuery?

Meu problema é o seguinte, preciso receber o resultado final dessa url:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=-12.9945,-38.5266&sensor=false

E preciso recuperar esse resultado através do JavaScript.

Comment: Nenhuma das respostas atende sua dúvida?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uma variante sem jQuery, inpirado [**aqui**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642289/return-html-content-as-a-string-given-url-javascript-function):

```
var url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=-12.9945,-38.5266&sensor=false';
httpGet(url);

function httpGet(theUrl) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var objectResposta = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.response);  // usando JSON.parse()
            console.log(objectResposta.results);                // log para a consola
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", theUrl, false);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

No caso do google maps isto funciona porque ele permite pedidos de domínios diferentes, mas noutros casos pode não funcionar por causa do *príncipio da mesma origem e [CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/145493/129)* / Partilha de recursos em origens diferentes).

Comment: Ctrl+C Ctrl+V vicia: o Ajax é IE5+, enquanto o `JSON.parse` é IE8+. Parece que todo mundo esqueceu disso.

Comment: @GustavoRodrigues, verdade :P editei...

Answer (score 10):

Use o [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/):

```
$.getJSON(url, function (resultado){
  // use o resultado
});
```

Comment: Não vai dar, é cross-domain.

Comment: Use ̶j̶s̶o̶n̶p̶ ̶o̶u̶ cors: a url retorna `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` no header.

Comment: Realmente, CORS liberado: http://jsfiddle.net/jGp8N/

Comment: É uma API do Google Maps. Se não fosse liberado iria fazer as pessoas se perderem. Literalmente.

Answer (score 1):

Assim como o colega @Gustavo Rodrigues respondeu, o código abaixo funcionou perfeitamente:

```js
$.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/jsonlatlng=-12.9945,-38.5266&sensor=false', null, function (data) {
    alert(data.results[1].address_components[0].long_name); // Resultado: "Av. 7 de Setembro, S/N"
})
```

Testei em uma página html simples e em uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Uma boa sugestão também.

```
var ajax = function(url, requestType, callback, queryString) {
    var ids = ['MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0',
    'MSXML2.XMLHTTP',
    'Microsoft.XMLHTTP'],
    xhr;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else {
      for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        try {
          xhr = new ActiveXObject(ids[i]);
          break;
        } catch(e) {}
      }
    };
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState== 4){
            if(xhr.status==200)
                 callback(xhr);          
        }        
    };
    xhr.open(requestType, url, true);
    if (requestType.toUpperCase() === 'GET')      
      xhr.send();
    else if (requestType.toUpperCase() === 'POST')
      xhr.send(queryString);      
};
ajax("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=-12.9945,-38.5266&sensor=false","GET",function(xhr){
   var ResultJSON = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
   console.log(ResultJSON);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Já que vc está usando o google maps para fazer isso, uma maneira de se fazer é usar a própria api que eles disponibilizam.

Aqui um exemplo:

http://jsfiddle.net/moykn/N6x3q/