# Qual é o significado de CORS?

Tags: terminologia, cors

Sempre vejo a palavra *CORS* relacionada a um erro ocorrido ao tentar fazer uma requisição `XmlHttpRequest` para uma determinada página, que não tenha o mesmo domínio como origem.

Exemplo:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1' is therefore not allowed access.

Mas qual é o significado da palavra *CORS*?

Essa palavra é usada para definir o erro ocorrido, ou alguma política de segurança dos  navegadores?

Comment: *Cross-Origin Resource Sharing*. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Answer (score 26, accepted):

CORS (*Cross-Origin Resource Sharing* em Inglês e [*Compartilhamento de recursos de origem cruzada* em português](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)) é um acordo sobre como trocar recursos entre browser e servidor quando o browser tenta aceder a um domínio diferente daquele em que está a navegar.

É um conjunto de regras, [uma especificação da W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), para que tipo de recursos podem ser acedidos, e como os limitar. Estas regras são implementadas pelos browsers/navegadores, e é este (o browser) que limita o acesso.

Estas regras impuseram-se por razões de segurança. Para evitar que scripts na página possam aceder livremente e fazer pedidos a outros sites e interagir com eles.

Na parte do servidor pode ou não "abrir-se" a porta a um, vários ou todos os pedidos/domínios. Esta implementação é específica da linguagem mas no fundo implica que haja *headers* presentes que o browser possa ler:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * // <- aberto para todos
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com:8080 http://foo.example.com // <- só estes dois dominios podem aceder
```

#### Em relação ao erro:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1' is therefore not allowed access.

Quando o browser lê no url por exemplo `http:` ele assume que é um url externo. Na verdade `http://localhost/` devia ser interpretado como "mesmo domínio" mas por causa do `http` o browser pensa que não é... Para resolver esse problema, que se aplica também em domínios online, deve usar-se caminhos relativos, e não absolutos com `http... etc`.

#### Mais leitura:

. **Wikipedia:** https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

. **W3C:** https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/ <sub>Em Inglês</sub>

. **MDN:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS <sub>Em Inglês</sub>

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, vou adicionar junto a uma resposta que dei sobre o assunto :D

Comment: A quem deu `-1`: podem comentar para eu melhorar a resposta :)