# Problemas com XMLHttpRequest no Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, requisição

Após esta atualização do Google Chrome para a versão 53, estou enfrentando problemas nas chamadas Ajax (jQuery), $.http (AngularJS) e XMLHttpRequest (Javascript) apresentando a seguinte mensagem:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load *. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '*' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.
```

Em chamada similar de outro serviço, com as mesmas características, recebi a seguinte mensagem:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load *. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '*' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.
```

Um exemplo de chamada é a seguinte:

```
var data = JSON.stringify(false);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("PUT", "*");
xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");

xhr.send(data);
```

Também não consigo executar no Firefox e Internet Explorer, porém, antes funcionava no Chrome, quando faça as chamadas no Postman ou método Backend elas são executadas corretamente.

Estou enfrentando este problema porque estou implementando uma das api's em uma landing page sem backend, por isso preciso utilizar apenas chamada Javascript ou jQuery a página.

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/145490/132

Comment: @VictorStafusa eu estou consumindo uma API externa, então, tem que ter http, e é api usada por outras empresas em dominios diferentes, então, tecnicamente, lá já está correto, e eu consigo fazer chamadas de backend (php, .net) mas não estou conseguindo via client side

Answer (score 3):

Isso:

```
 xhr.open("PUT", "*");
```

Não faz sentido, o segundo parametro no `open` deve ser uma URL ou caminho relativo, `*` não parece uma URL "valida".

Veja esta parte da mensagem de erro:

> The response had HTTP status code 405.

O código 405 indica método não permitido, que se refere ao uso do `PUT`, `GET`, etc, mas no seu caso provavelmente é o URL que usou como asterisco `*`.

Provavelmente o que deseja é algo como:

```
 xhr.open("PUT", "/foo/bar");
```

O problema do `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` já foi falado várias vezes no site:

Pesquisa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=No+Access-Control-Allow-Origin

A url que está tentando acessar é externa ou um sub-dominio, para permitir esse tipo de requisição (de dominios diferentes).

Comment: o caminho é uma url de uma api externa, tipo http://www.api.com.br/

Comment: e eu pesquisei, a chamada esta intermitente, em alguns poucos momentos funciona e em outros não, estive conversando com algumas pessoas e parece que é algum problema em minha rede interna da empresa...