# Como pegar url de iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

Eu tenho um iframe que recebe um endereço "ex.com" e este endereço quando entra nele já é redirecionado a um outro link `"ex.com?id=foo&exemplo=bar"`.
eu gostaria que quando o iframe redirecionar, um javascript pegue o novo url do iframe e emita um alert mostrando o valor de id e de exemplo ou armazene eles em variaveis, pois eu irei usar estes valores.

Comment: A página dentro da iFrame está no mesmo dominio que a página que contém am iFrame?

Comment: Se é outro dominio tens limitações de CORS e iso só é permitido se a página o permitir, normalmente não permite. Sabes se essa página limita via CORS?

Comment: tipo eu só quero pegar o link em que o iframe redireciona , 
se cria uma pagina  e nela colcoa um redirecionamento para qualquer outro lugar com um as string no final id=ddsg&exemplo=dsgs 
ai coloca isso em um iframe  e pega o valor de id e exemplo 

não sei não ;) eu sou novo nisso estou estudando entende...

Comment: Dá uma olhada [aqui sobre CORS](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/145490/129). Diz qual é a página que queres usar se não sabes ver se está protegida, mas provavelmente não permite o acesso ao que queres e não há volta a dar.

Comment: eu criei um form que faz uma requisição get  para uma outra pagina exemplo?id=355345&nome=Fabio
e este from fica dentro de um iframe, eu queria pega o valor de id e de nome e coloca em um alert assim "355345//Fabio" e logo em seguida a pagina(não o iframe) será redirecionada a um link qualquer .