# Problema com fontes e url

Tags: css, url, css-font-face

Então moçada, eu to com um problema aqui que é o seguinte, eu importo fontes externas no css com o @font-face, só que quando acesso o meu site no navegador sem colocar o www, o site não puxa a fonte . Mas se eu digito o endereço na url do site com www ele pega a fonte externa certinho.

Eu uso o chrome e está atualizado, já limpei o cache.

O console me dá um erro de ***has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.***

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual é o significado de CORS?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/145490/qual-%c3%a9-o-significado-de-cors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,
isso deve ser causado por que seu domínio não está redirecionando as requisições de http://seudominio para http://www.seudominio onde estão fixadas as urls das fontes verifica no seu site qual o link "padrão" acredito que seja o http://seudominio muda o link para a forma correta que deve ficar tudo certo.