# Como pegar todos o href de outra pagina externa

Tags: jquery

Eu gostaria de acessar uma pagina externa([google](http://google.com) por exemplo), e dentro dele rodar um script para capturar todos os hrefs, eu li sobre o fato dos navegadores não permitirem usar GET para pegar o html, mas acredito que deva ter uma forma de fazer isso, tenho esse codigo por enquanto.
Eu li sobre o googlebot, e gostaria de tentar fazer isso em JS.

```
$.ajax({   
    url: 'http://google.com',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(res) {
        $('a').each(function() {
            alert($this.href);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: _"mas acredito que deva ter uma forma de fazer isso"_ - se o site não quiser permitir isso (CORS fechado) então não dá, por razões de segurança/privacidade. A única opção é fazer no servidor.

Comment: Não há uma forma de simular um usuário, ou navegador, já que eu posso acessar normalmente, há uma forma de simular isso ??

Comment: Se houvesse uma maneira de simular o usuário então podias disparar cliques em anúncios ou likes no youtube via ajax e enganar o sistema. É para prevenir isso. Dá uma olhada sobre CORS https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/145493/129

Answer (score 0):

Você não ira conseguir fazer isso apenas com o frontend pelos motivos explicados nos comentários de sua publicação. Usando nodejs você consegue fazer isso. No código abaixo pego todos as tags `a` de um site e em seguida obtenho o conteúdo do atributo href de cada uma.

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var searchTerm = 'screen+scraping';
//URL DO SITE 
var url = 'http://www.meusite.com.br';

request(url, function(err, resp, body){
  //CARREGA O HTML
  $ = cheerio.load(body);
  links = $('a'); //Pega todas as tags a, exatamente como o jquery

  //Passa por todas as tags obtidas no trecho acima.
  $(links).each(function(i, link){
    //Na tag pega o atributo href e imprime no console.
    console.log($(link).text() + ':\n  ' + $(link).attr('href'));
  });
});
```