# REST - O que é CORS?

Tags: spring, restful, jax-rs

Estou começando no desenvolvimento de aplicações RESTful, com Spring e JAX-RS e percebi que alguns sistemas criam um tal de CORS, não ter CORS configurado na aplicação teria qual impacto exatamente?

Comment: O CORS não é a configuração em si, ele se refere a algo que requisita diferentes origens, tipo vc tem uma pagina HTTP em um dominio chamado `xyz.com` e você via Ajax tenta chamar `abc.com/foo/bar`, veja que os dominios são diferentes, então ocorre o problema, pois por segurança o navegador irá barrar isto, então para que possa "compartilhar" (o S é de Sharing provavelmente) será necessário adicionar no `abc.com/foo/bar` headers para liberar um tipo de acesso conforme necessário/customizavel ...

Comment: ... podendo liberar que só alguns vs específicos acessem o `abc.com` ou até mesmo liberar qualquer domínio, as pessoas costumam liberar todo e qualquer domínio, o que ***nem sempre*** é ideal, pois isso fugiria do controle, mas tem casos que é necessário, conforme a necessidade do sistema. Para mais detalhes sobre como permitir um domínio ser acessado por outros especifico ou por vários outros veja as respostas da pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/145490/3635, se quiser configurar algo **especifico** faça uma nova pergunta detalhada.

Comment: Excelente explicação, por fim eu entendi rs...