# Como o postman consegue enviar requisições sem ter problemas de cors?

Tags: angular, http, postman

Atualmente utilizo Angular 2+ em algumas aplicações e estou sentindo dificuldades em resolver problemas de cors. Quando a requisição é feita pelo Postman, tudo ocorre conforme esperado, porém quando tento através da minha aplicação, é lançado erro de cors no console informando que o controle de headers content type não está autorizado.

Tentei adicionar na minha requisição alguns headers para tentar permitir qualquer tipo de requisição.

Tentei algo como:

```
let header = new HttpHeaders();

    header = header.set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    header.append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
```

Também tentei todos os outros tipos de headers para cors disponíveis que encontrei, access control origin, enfim, todos continuo tendo problema no cors.

Li que a melhor forma de tratar o cors é habilitando no servidor. Porém fiquei curioso em como o postman consegue realizar as requisições sem que estejam configuradas no servidor.

Seria uma falha do angular não conseguir mandar esses headers de forma a permitir? Seria um macete do Postman que consegue ignorar isso?

Muito curioso.

Comment: O CORS é um problema de segurança que o navegador reconhece, cross origin, quando é utilizado o postman, ele sabe que é um aplicativo do proprio navegador que está testando e não vai funcionar como uma aplicação real.

Para funcionar o cors, você precisa habilitar ele na sua aplicação server side, e na cliente side, passar o tipo de cabeçalho que está indo, caso contrario não vai funcionar

Comment: O CORS é implementado pelo navegador, se o software que está usando não quiser implementa-lo, é decisão dele. Da uma olhada no que é [CORS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/145490/qual-%c3%a9-o-significado-de-cors)

Comment: Uma coisa que fiz e funcionou. Criei um atalho do Chrome e adicionei na chamada do .exe

Ex.:  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security