# Política de segurança Navegadores Servidores

Tags: php, javascript, visual-studio, apache-cordova

Olá, sobre o `CORS`, dei uma boa olhada [neste link, aqui do SOPT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/145490/qual-%C3%A9-o-significado-de-cors/145493#145493), mas ao testar, na prática, constatei algo interessante.
Usando o código abaixo num projeto com XAMPP e Notepad++, eu tenho o impedimento de acesso à página/arquivo [meuPHP.php], porém, usando o Cordova no Visual Studio, o qual cria um emulador próprio, ele acessa o tal arquivo `php` e recebe o retorno `AJAX`. Por que isso? No projeto Cordova eu não coloco nada sobre `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`. Não tem nada sobre esse cabeçalho. Ao passo que, se eu colocar tal cabeçalho no arquivo teste do Notepad++, com servidor XAMPP e tals, ele acessa, mas, repito, o Cordova, no Visual Studio não tem esse cabeçalho e acessa mesmo assim. O que explica isso?

```
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://www.meuProjeto.com/meuPHP.php",
        async: true,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (dados) {
            for (var i = 0; dados.length > i; i++) {
                $('body').append('<p>'+dados[i].id);
            }
            }
        });
```

Continuando...
preciso saber dessa situação por questão de segurança.

Comment: Não sei se é esse o caso, mas CORS só se aplica a requisições feitas pelo browser