# crawler em javascript

Tags: javascript, web-crawler

Atualmente eu desenvolvo crawler em php usando o guzzle, e ultimamente estive procurando se seria possivel usar javascript para criar crawler, usando o ip do usuario e tal, vocês sabem se e possivel? se não for sabe o motivo ou se alguem ja tentou?

Comment: JavaScript em node.js sim, JavaScript browser não é possivel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme colocado pelo [Guilherme Nascimento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3635/guilherme-nascimento) nos comentários, você pode desenvolver um *crawler* em JavaScript utilizando Node.js. Existem até bibliotecas que te ajudam, através de um *headless browser* (sem interface visual, apenas programável), como o [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev). Assim, você só precisa fazer uma requisição para uma página web e, com o HTML obtido, usar o Puppeteer para *inspecioná-lo*.

No browser, por outro lado, não é possível, uma vez que mesmo que tenhamos [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) disponível, nem sempre conseguiríamos efetuar requisições à outras páginas web, principalmente em razão das [políticas de segurança CORS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/145490/qual-%C3%A9-o-significado-de-cors).