# Requisição axios com basic autenticação não funciona

Tags: javascript, axios

Fiz um simples programa para buscar o token do usuário, porém ele necessita de um Basic Authentication, o que tem me dado o erro abaixo.

Onde estou errando?

Meu código:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:meu_acesso()"><b>Acessar</b></a>
<script src="axios.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function meu_acesso() {
    var session_url = 'https://treinagedave.sp.gov.br/gedave/api/spservicos/v1/login';
    var uname = "wsService";
    var pass = "%$c55e3y5y7n522$%";    
    var p_cpf = "12345678901";
    var p_senha =  "pass0001";   

    axios.post
    ( session_url, 
       { params: { cpf: p_cpf, senha: p_senha } }
      ,{ headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                  , "Accept": "application/json"
                  , 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                   } }
      ,{ auth: { username: uname, password: pass } }
    )
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log('Authenticated' + response);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log('Error on Authentication' + error);
    });
 }
</script>
```

Resultado:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://treinagedave.sp.gov.br/gedave/api/spservicos/v1/login' from origin 'http://www.sistemas24horas.com.br' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Error on AuthenticationError: Network Error   axios.min.js:8 POST https://treinagedave.sp.gov.br/gedave/api/spservicos/v1/login net::ERR_FAILED
```

Comment: Me parece que o erro se deve à política de CORS. Isto responde à sua pergunta? **[Qual é o significado de CORS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/145490/qual-%c3%a9-o-significado-de-cors)**

Comment: Pelo que pesquisei concordo com você. Hoje eu realizo esse acesso numa aplicação Android com código Java, passando o user/pass de autenticação, recebendo de retorno um json. Tenho que aplicar isso num site e recuperar esses dados do usuário, porem não estou conseguindo fazer essa autenticação, já tentei várias formas, passei alguns parâmetros para o axios, mas sem resultado, sempre dá o mesmo erro. Teria alguma outra forma de aplicar isso?

Comment: Isso acontece porque o cliente de requisições do Android não leva em conta as políticas de CORS, que são algo primariamente implementado para adicionar uma fina camada de segurança nos navegadores. Se você tiver acesso ao servidor que está tentando alcançar, pode adicionar alguns cabeçalhos HTTP (relacionados ao CORS) que te permitam fazer as requisições do seu website via AJAX. Esse é o caso?

Comment: Sim, tenho acesso ao servidor. Você poderia me informar qual o parâmetro de cabeçalho que devo informar ao axios para buscar os dados?

Answer (score 1):

O erro que você está sofrendo se deve às políticas de segurança do [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Controle_Acesso_CORS), implementadas nos navegadores mais modernos. Para saber mais, leia [esta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/145490/qual-%C3%A9-o-significado-de-cors).

Desse modo, você deve adicionar cabeçalhos no seu servidor que permitem que a aplicação seja consumida por qualquer origem, o que atualmente não é o caso.

Alguns dos cabeçalhos que o seu servidor deve enviar na resposta (`response`) são estes:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
```

Ele irá permitir que qualquer cliente seja capaz, de qualquer origem no navegador, acessar os recursos da sua aplicação no servidor. Você pode trocar o asterísco por um URL especificando qual origem pode consumir o recurso.

Vale lembrar que essas medidas de segurança só valem no navegador.

[Esta documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Controle_Acesso_CORS) na MDN explica sobre o CORS bem mais a fundo.