# Como habilitar o CORS

Tags: javascript, cors

Estou tentando fazer uma requisição RSS de um site mas gostaria de saber como eu habilitar o cors sem burlar como esta no código. Lembrando que não tenho acesso ao servidor no qual quero realizar a requisição.

```html
<head>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      const RSS_URL = "site que quero realizar a requisição";
      const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";//Burlando a validação do cors
      fetch(proxyurl + RSS_URL)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(str => new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/xml"))
        .then(data => {
          console.log(data);
          const items = data.querySelectorAll("item");
          let html =`
          <div class="container">
            <h1>that's it</h1>
            </div>
          `;
          items.forEach(el => {
            html +=`
        <div class="container"> 
        <article>
          <h2 class="textStyle">
            <a href="${el.querySelector("link").innerHTML}" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
              ${el.querySelector("title").innerHTML}
            </a>
          </h2>
        </article>
        </div>
      `;
          });
          document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
        });
    }
  </script>
</head>
```

Gostaria de saber a maneira certa de realizar isso. Sou iniciante em JavaScript.

Comment: Relacionado: [Qual é o significado de CORS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/145490/3774)

Comment: adicione o retorno CORS

Comment: além de definir o crossorigin como anonymous, você ainda vai está sujeito a configurações do servidor que hospedará sua página, e ao que hospeda oque você deseja pegar... são configurações que ajudam bastante a proteger seus usuarios de ataques como o XSS... , recomendo que você implemente do lado do servidor um cache local do RSS para evitar blechas de segurança... ou mesmo caso o servidor externo não aceite... torna seu site "possivel de funcionar"

Comment: de acordo com a configuração do servidor, seu cliente recebera via cabeçalhos do HTTP, as propriedades que definem, se será permitido ou não este comportamento da página